# ¿Cómo repetir una imagen de fondo sobre el eje "Y" puesta en un div contenedor al hacer responsive la página?

Tags: responsive

Buenos días, tengo el sitio [Cuadernillo Latinbooks](http://latinbooksint.com/cuadernillos/index.html) funcionando de manera correcta en el modo pantalla de escritorio, ahora estoy intentando hacer responsive el sitio, pero no encuentro la manera de poder aplicar el mismo fondo a todo cuando paso a tamaño dispositivo. Actualmente el fondo se encuentra en un div que contiene todo el sitio y está con position:absolute. La idea es hacer que el mismo fondo se repita verticalmente hasta cubrir todo el alto de la página de manera automatica segun la resolución de cada dispositivo.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que el fondo se repita solo en el eje Y con la propiedad `background-repeat:repeat-y;` lo puedes lograr

Comment: Ya lo tiene aplicado, pero por algun motivo no hace nada

Comment: @NicolasDure y lo tienes dentro de un "@media screen" ?

Comment: Si, en el html el div q contiene la img, en el css las propiedades para que el fondo este absoluto en modo escritorio, y ahora estaba configurando un media queri a 320px de ancho, aplique la propiedad que me decis tanto en el estilo normal como en el media queri, pero nada, no lo repite

Comment: @NicolasDure si pones tu codigo en la pregunta seria mucho mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

A las `img` con id **fondo, fondo2, fondo3** quitales el width:100%, y comprueba el resultado en modo responsive

Comment: solo deje el div id fondo, los otros era para tratar de llegar mas abajo con el fondo, probé sacarle el width:100% al media @media para 320px de resolución, pero no modificó nada. Solo toma su tamaño original en el sitio, pero no llega a cubrir la totalidad del alto de la página

Comment: mira ahora mismo acabo de probar con el inspector del navegador , puse l sitio en responsive, a fondo2 y 3 , les puse `display:none` para quitarlos y al id **fondo**, lo quite el `width:100%`, y al momento se acoplo el fondo

Comment: mira ponle en **estilos.css**  : #fondo{ position:absolut; z-index:-1;  left:0;  } , cambia el que tienes por este y dime si no es lo que querias

Comment: Reemplace el codigo por este que me decis, pero sucede lo mismo, el fondo no llega hasta abajo de todo en el modo responsive. Ahora se me ocurrio poner el position en modo fixed, parece funcionar, se ve bien en ambos modos ahora :)

Comment: recuerda que el modo fixed fija el elemento en el DOM , y tienes que tener en cuanta eso , pero bueno fijando el fondo y haciendo el scroll a los elementos por encima espero te sirva

Comment: Si, de momento no parece generarme ningun problema por sobre los elementos, y cumple la función de llegar hasta el final con el scroll. Muchas gracias por la ayuda @Travv